# Dot "power" of a matrix

Tags: matrices, dimensional-analysis

By analogy with the matrix product is there a name for the matrix "power" operation defined by
$$y_i = \prod_j x_j^{a_{ij}}?$$
For example:
$$\left( \begin{array}{lll}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{array}\right)
\star
\left( \begin{array}{lll}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
 =
\left( \begin{array}{lll}
x_1^{a_{11}}x_2^{a_{12}}x_3^{a_{13}} &
x_2^{a_{21}}x_2^{a_{22}}x_3^{a_{23}} &
x_3^{a_{31}}x_3^{a_{32}}x_3^{a_{33}}
\end{array}\right)$$
I have come across this application in dimensional analysis where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of physical constants in one unit system and $\mathbf{A}$ the matrix of corresponding powers of dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not normally given its own name, because it isn't really useful.

But you could take:

$$\left( \begin{array}{lll}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{l}
\log x_1\\
\log x_2\\
\log x_3\end{array}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}\log y_1\\ \log y_2\\ \log y_3\end{pmatrix}$$

using normal matrix multiplication, and get the same result.

So, it's a special case of the normal multiplication, and it doesn't occur enough to really warrant its own notation or name. I suppose you could call it "logarithmic linear transformation," but it's just likely to confuse people.

The altered question is the same, only with the transpose of what I wrote:

$$\left( \begin{array}{lll}
\log x_1 &\log x_2 & \log x_3\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{lll}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
 =
\left( \begin{array}{lll}
\log y_1 &
\log y_2 &
\log y_3
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry - I've just corrected my equation. I can see that your conversion to the regular matrix product would still hold with some modification, though.

Comment: It's just the transpose of what I wrote.